# (No Action Needed), (I'm Done) & (Skip) buttons are not working on click after scrolling down due to overlapping

Tags: bug, review, design

I found UI overlapping issue here https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/25622634

And Top-Right side all three buttons are not working on click after scrolling down due to z-index or overlapping issue.

[image]